# Using pointers to access row wise data inside map in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures

I have following data structure that stores result from database,

```
//       column name,    array of (row values)
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> dataset;
```

This will have values vector of string values for each column and I can quickly access each column values by

```
dataset["columnName"][rowIndex];
```

Sometimes, I also want to access all columns of complete row, this will require complex code like,

```
std::vector<std::string> getRow(unsigned int rowIndex)
{
    std::vector<std::string> row_data;
    for(auto& col : dataset)
        row_data.emplace(col[0]);
    return row_data;
}
```

Is this implementation to access row data efficient enough? Can I keep another map in row wise orientation with pointer to values in dataset? How to do it?

Something like,

```
         row Index,     array of (  pointer  to  string value in dataset)
std::map<unsigned long, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>> point;
```

Comment: Rather use indices than pointers to remember particular data items from a `std::vector`, pointers aren't stable.

Comment: Your row data or your vector of strings has a size parameter use it as an indexing mechanism.

Comment: How often do you call the function `getRow`? If rarely, this way is sufficient. Otherwise, I would suggest putting all data in a 2D matrix instead of a series of vectors.

Answer (score 0):

If you always need the complete row, I would not know how to make it more efficient, however when you also need only some entries in a given row, I would use something like that:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> > MAP;

class MapRow{
    public:
        MapRow(MAP* map, unsigned int row) : map(map),row(row){}

        std::string& operator[](std::string col){
            return (*map)[col][row];
        }
        const std::string& operator[](std::string col) const {
            return (*map)[col][row];
        }   
    private:
        MAP* map;
        unsigned int row;
};
```